# Mouse Control using Native Client

Tags: event-handling, mouseevent, google-nativeclient

I have a doubt and I still searching how I could do this.
Can I make a Native Client application that controls mouse cursor? Like this: I want to control my mouse cursor using my keyboard arrows in a Native Client application.

I would appreciate your help/direction, thanks!

Comment: For security reasons, this must not become possible.

Comment: Oh, thought that this was the answer, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible with a Firebreath plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a NaCl application because there is no API available to control the mouse cursor position.

This is possible if you develop a Pepper plugin because Pepper plugins can call the native OS API, so the question becomes how do I control the mouse cursor programmatically on platform X?

http://code.google.com/p/ppapi/

John

Comment: Hmm, great! Now, looking for another solution